# Как задать имя сайта и опубликовать его?

Tags: веб-программирование

Например, я написал сайт HTML и как мне потом быть, как задать имя сайта, и как опубликовать?

Comment: Зачем? Смысл вообще?

Comment: - Доктор, я буду жить?  
 - А смысл?  
  
Это я к чему: google в помощь. Если что-то непонятно на практике, обращайтесь.

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая начинающий уровень вопроса, для начала достаточно тренироваться на самых простых хостингах, вроде narod.ru.

1. Зарегистрировать доменное имя у регистратора (reg.ru и т.п.).
2. Зарегистрировать учетную запись у хостера (narod.yandex.ru).
3. Залить файл на хостинг (через панель или ftp).
4. Привязать доменное имя к хостингу (http://help.yandex.ru/narod/?id=1112401).